# Can two overlapping disconnected graphs contain a Euler Circuit or Path? Hamilton Circuit or Path?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can two overlapping disconnected graphs contain a Euler Circuit or Path? Hamilton Circuit or Path?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eulerian/Hamiltonian graphs are necessarily connected. It is not possible to traverse all edges or visit all the vertices without the graph being connected.